# Supercharging the axiom schema of replacement in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am interested in seeing a proof of the following in $\text{ZFC}$?

---

Proposition 1 : Suppose there is a mapping

$\tag 1 x \mapsto \psi(x)$

that can associate to any set $x$ another set $\psi(x)$. Then for any set $A$ there exist a set $B$ satisfying

$\tag 2 A \subset B$
$\tag 3 \psi[B] = \{\psi(x): x\in B\} \subset B$

---

It seems like a trivial result but I am a weak in $\text{ZFC}$ formalism and so any clarification/elucidation/rejection here would be appreciated. The statement of proposition 1 itself might be 'rough around the edges', as it lacks the precision found in the wikipedia exposition of

[6. Axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#6._Axiom_schema_of_replacement)

It appears that proposition 1 can be used to prove the axiom schema of replacement since we can extend a mapping $f$ on any set $A$ via

$\tag 4 f:x \mapsto \emptyset \; \text{ for } x \text{ any set not an element of } A$

> Can the above theory be put on a firm footing?

Comment: I suspect you mean "$\psi[B]$" - that is, $\{\psi(x): x\in B\}$ - rather than "$\psi(B)$" in your (3)? Otherwise the proposition is false: taking $\psi(x)=\{x\}$ we never have $\psi(B)\subseteq B$ for any $B$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Yes - edited the question.

Comment: Supercharging? So the battery is full in 20 minutes?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose we could change it to supersetting, since we are looking for a superset, and after we find it we can do a some supersets at the gym to relax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo my comment above, this is indeed a rephrasing of replacement. Informally (formalizing everything here is a good exercise), fix $\psi$ and $A$ as above. For each $n\in\omega$ and $a\in A$ there is a unique $b$ such that there is a length-$(n+1)$ sequence whose first term is $a$, whose last term is $b$, and whose $(i+1)$th term is $\psi$ applied to its $i$th term. Intuitively this $b$ is just $\psi^n(a)$; note that $\psi^0(a)=a$ by this definition.

We can now treat this as an instance of replacement starting on $\omega\times A$; the resulting set $B$ is intuitively the set of all things that can be gotten from elements of $A$ by repeatedly applying $\psi$. This $B$ has the desired properties.

---

As to formalism, the principle in the OP should (like the separation and replacement axioms) be formulated as a *scheme*, consisting of a separate instance for each formula $\psi$ (and a bit of care taken to allow parameters).

Comment: By using the $\text{(4)}$ 'extension' can this 'instance of replacement' be used to prove prove $\quad$ 6. Axiom schema of replacement $\quad$ ?