# Merging the axiom of infinity into a 'supercharged' axiom of replacement in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The reader should review the (short) question/answer

$\quad$ [Supercharging the axiom schema of replacement in ZFC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3410502/432081)

before proceeding here.

---

Drop both

$\quad$ [6. Axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#6._Axiom_schema_of_replacement)

and

$\quad$ [7. Axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#7._Axiom_of_infinity)

from $\text{ZFC}$, giving $\text{ZFC} \setminus \{(6), (7)\}$

Introduce the new schema,

$\quad 6_{sc}$ Axiom schema of sc-replacement

giving a new framework $[\text{ZFC} \setminus \{(6), (7)\}]+(6_{sc})$.

Consider the following argument:

Let ${\displaystyle S(x)}$ abbreviate ${\displaystyle x\cup \{x\}}$ where ${\displaystyle x}$ is some set. So we have a mapping

$\tag 1 \psi: x \mapsto S(x)$

defined on all sets.

Let $A = \{\emptyset\}$ be the primitive singleton set. Applying axiom $(6_{sc})$ there is a set $B$ satisfying

$\tag 2 A \subset B$
$\tag 3 \psi[B] = \{\psi(x): x\in B\} \subset B$

The set $B$ is not finite.

> Are we back in 'ZFC land'?

Notwithstanding the assistance given by Noah Schweber (background post) and Andrés E. Caicedo, a detailed proof showing how

$\quad [\text{ZFC} \setminus \{(6), (7)\}]+(6_{sc}) \text{ implies } (6)$

would certainly wrap this up. I would attempt it myself but it would be an 'all thumbs' mess!

Comment: Yes. ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo So this is immediate or are you relying on pubs/research?

Comment: It is immediate. The one thing you may find interesting is that any axiom that implies the existence of an infinite set (over a "reasonable" subtheory of ZF) implies the usual axiom of infinity. I have discussed some version of this observation on this site before.

Comment: I too recall a few discussions on this.